# Passing Props to a Component in React Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, mern

Can you explain what this line? What props and {...props} does ?

```
<Route exact path='/' render={props => <Home {...props} />} />
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation

TLDR; Those props passed in render indicate as `route-props` which provides you `match`,`location` and `history` objects through which you can route through components or utilize those objects way you want in child components(if passed through props).

`{...props}` just supplies all the properties it has in object. `...` is known as spread syntax which helps to get **all the existing properties** in the object mentioned(here `props`). Like passing down the data component don't need it now but will be required by children through current component structure.

Here `{...props}` will yield to `match,location and history` passed to component in `render`

#### React Router API

Source - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

> **Route props**
>
> All three render methods will be passed the same three route props
>
> - match
> - location
> - history
>
> **Render (function)**
>
> Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop receives all the same route props as the component render prop.

Those props are internal API of `react-router` v4. You can see more about `render` method of `<Route>` component

If you pass a component and those props in that component(child), you can log the props and you'll find all of the three props provided by `route-props`

Props in child (if you log in console in child component) :
`Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined}`

**Example**

You can find example codesandbox I have curated just for this example - https://codesandbox.io/embed/0m1z1xwxnw

**Alternative**

If you don't want to use `render` to internally render component you want, you can use `withRouter` HOC and wrap your component into that HOC as `export default withRouter(WrappedComponent)` and it will provide all three objects you want i.e. `match`,`location` and `history` and hence appending it into `props` object

Answer (score 1):

`...props` is called the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and is used to pass every property in the `props` object as a separate prop to the `Home` component.

It might be easier to see why this works if you compiled the JSX to `React.createElement` calls.

```
React.createElement(Home, {
  ...props
});
```

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
};

const props = {
  baz: 'baz',
  ...obj
};

console.log(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put your props in brackets, just like this: `<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Home {...props} />} />`